# useFieldArray , Shadcn/ui, AsyncSelect, Zod ,I get the error "undefined" or "Expected string, received object." when validating zod

Tags: next.js, undefined, react-hook-form, react-select, zod

Immediately apologize for my poor English.

I am encountering an issue while validating a form using useFieldArray. Instead of receiving the error text 'At least one location is required,' I am getting 'undefined.' The error disappears as expected when I select something in the dropdown.

Here is how the fields look right after adding them: [form, select + error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQO5d.jpg)

The error disappears as expected when I select something in the dropdown."

These changes aim to provide a smoother flow and clearer expression of the issue you're facing.

ZodError

```
[
{
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "array",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
        "location"
    ],
    "message": "Required"
}
```

]

Code:

```js
"use client";

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useFieldArray, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";

import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";

import { useTransition } from "react";
import {
  Form,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";

const NOMINATIM_BASE_URL = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?";

const locationSchema = z
  .object({
    label: z.string().min(1, { message: "At least one location is required" }),
    value: z.object({
        lat: z.string(),
        lon: z.string(),
      }),
  })

const formSchema = z.object({
  location: z
    .array(locationSchema).min(1, { message: "min 1" }),
});

const result = formSchema.safeParse({ location: [{}] });
if (!result.success) {
  console.log("result.error.issues: ", result.error.issues);
  console.log("result.error.format(): ", result.error.format().location?.[0]);
}

// component
export default function DAddCar_A() {
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  const loadOptions = async (inputValue: string) => {
    if (inputValue.length >= 3) {
      const params: Record<string, string | number> = {
        q: inputValue,
        format: "json",
        addressdetails: 1,
        polygon_geojson: 0,
      };
      const queryString = new URLSearchParams(
        params as Record<string, string>
      ).toString();
      const requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
      };

      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `${NOMINATIM_BASE_URL}${queryString}`,
          requestOptions
        );
        const result = await response.json();

        const options = result.map((city: any) => ({
          label: city.name,
          value: {
            lat: city.lat,
            lon: city.lon,
          },
        }));

        return options;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error fetch API:", err);
        return [];
      }
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  };

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    mode: "onChange",
  });

  const {
    fields: locationFields,
    remove: locationRemove,
    append: locationAppend,
  } = useFieldArray({
    control: form.control,
    name: "location",
  });

  function onSubmit(data: any) {
    startTransition(async () => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="w-2/3 space-y-6">
        {locationFields.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name={`location.${index}`}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Пункт</FormLabel>
                  <AsyncSelect
                    instanceId="location"
                    {...field}
                    // @ts-ignore
                    loadOptions={(inputValue, callback) =>
                      loadOptions(inputValue).then(callback)
                    }
                    isClearable
                    onChange={(value) =>
                      field.onChange(
                        value || {  label: "", value: { lat: "", lon: "" } }
                      )
                    }
                    defaultValue={field.value !== null ? field.value : null}
                  />
                  <FormMessage />
                  <Button onClick={() => locationRemove(index)}>Remove</Button>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
        <Button
          onClick={() =>
            locationAppend({
              label: "",
              value: {
                lat: "",
                lon: "",
              },
            })
          }>
          add
        </Button>
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

"I assumed that it might be necessary to specify name={location.${index}.label'}in theFormField`. In this case, when creating, I already get the error message 'String must contain at least 1 character(s),' but when choosing any option, I get the error 'Expected string, received object.'"

[form image + errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmwBk.jpg)